# Swiping a fragment not full page.

Tags: android, fragment, swipe

I currently have 1 activity that jas 2 fragments top half and botton half.  I want to swipe the bottom fragment only. (java implented)

Before i go learning the wrong method could someone please tell me which method I should use.

Do you sill use pageView and a fragment adapter or something.

Any usefull tutorials that do similar would be good so i can figure it out.

Comment: Define a fragment(top) and viewpager(bottom) in activity and write the adapter for the viewpager, invoke the fragments into this pager.
All the best.

Comment: Got this to work was exactly what you said thanks for the guidance gvsharma

Answer (score 0):

Define fragment and viewpager in the same activity. in the fragment show thetop fragment and in viewpager, write one pager adapter and invoke all the child fragments into that pager. This solves your problem.

Your activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<space 
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
center_horizontal="true"
center_vertical="true"
android:layout_height="0.5dp">

<fragment 
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
layout_above="@id/space_layout"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.viewpager 
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
layout_below="@id/space_layout"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Then define PagerAdapter class and show all your child fragments in that.
all the best